# How to remove a trailing slash from phpBB url?

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, mediawiki, phpbb

I have followed some previously answered questions on here and rewrote my phpBB forum's main URL as follows:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*)/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]
```

The forum URL used to be

```
http://site.com/forum/index.php
```

Now it resolves successfully to

```
http://site.com/forum/
```

I would like to remove the final trailing slash.  What changes should i make to the code above?

P.S. I would need to make similar changes to the wiki page of the same site, which currently resolves to site.com/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page (I need it to be site.com/wiki)

Answer (score 0):

Add in

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/{1}$ $1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your .htaccess before your rewrite rule add this line:

```
DirectorySlash Off
```

to tell Apache to not to always append a trailing slash.

Comment: With that line added, going to the URL presents the visitor with my directory and file listing instead of loading the index.php

Comment: You have this condition `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` in your rule that's why it doesn't get forwarded to `index.php`. Comment out this line and then it will be forwarded.

Comment: Actually, this also happens when I only have DirectorySlash Off without any ReWriteEngine code.

Comment: Did you try removing `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` to test.

Comment: Yes, I removed that line.  It still exposes the directory listing when you enter the URL without a slash.

Comment: Hi, can you please help me troubleshoot this when you get a chance?  Thank you!